# Should model know its collection?

Tags: backbone.js

A collection knows its models, but is there a way for the model to get to its collection?

I would need a way to get to the "adjacent" models in a collection. The following may give a better idea of the problem:

I'm trying to implement a simple app that ranks items based on an "priority" attribute in the model and maintains a list of them. Each model view has buttons for increasing or decreasing the priority, which should alter the ordering of the list accordingly.
Simply adding or subtracting one from the current value will work as long as the priority-attributes are continuous, for example:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6
```

But there is also a delete button, which allows deleting any model from the list. It can lead to priority-attributes like:

```
1,2,5,6
```

Now changing the priority of 5 to 4 wont change the order of the list as it's still greater than 2.

Comment: Is the collection supposed to re-order based on priority?

Answer (score 4):

It's undocumented, but the models will automatically have a `collection` property that points to the collection.  I don't know the details of how that works if a model is in multiple collections (perhaps the `collection` property is not changed once it's set).

To solve the specific problem you mentioned, you can listen for `remove` events on the collection and adjust things accordingly.  In this case you don't even need that `collection` property, because both the model and collection will be passed to the `remove` listener.

```
var handler = function ( model, collection, options ) {

  // ...

};

collection.on( 'remove', handler );
```

The [Backbone.Collection docs](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-remove) also say this:

> the index at which the model is being removed from the collection is available as `options.index`

The `options` argument to `remove` listeners is not documented where the signature for `remove` listeners is [documented](http://backbonejs.org/#FAQ-events), but it is passed (in 0.9.2 anyway).

Comment: Good to know this, in the meanwhile I realized that simply listening to change events solves the entire problem: I can then find the adjacent models in the listener.

Comment: Yeah, I was originally going to say something about that, but then it sounded like you were just having a problem with the removal part.  If you listen for `change:priority` on the collection, you'll get the model as the first argument and can access the collection via `model.collection`, or if you don't want to rely on that you can register the listener as `collection.on( 'change:priority', handler, collection )` and then access the collection as `this` in the listener.